# PHP Laravel and SSH1 or SSH2 Not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ssh

So I am having an issue getting php ssh2 working in laravel. I assume laravel is causing the issue because it seems to do  that with external php libraries.
Here is what I have.

Test.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Core\Framework;    
use App\Core\Helpers\Libs\SSH\Net\Net_SSH1;

class SSHServer {
    public function __construct() {
        $ssh = new Net_SSH1("192.99.238.228");
        $ssh->login('root','password');
    }
}
```

My SSH1.php
http://pastebin.com/xyXtb89s

Here is the error I am getting.

```
    Use of undefined constant NET_SSH1_CMSG_EOF - assumed 'NET_SSH1_CMSG_EOF'
in SSH1.php line 1068
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Use of undefined constant NET_SSH1_CMSG_EOF - assumed 'NET_SSH1_CMSG_EOF'', '/home/admin/web/gamecp.treeboxservers.com/core/app/Core/Helpers/Libs/SSH/Net/SSH1.php', '1068', array('msg' => 'Client Quit')) in SSH1.php line 1068
at Net_SSH1->_disconnect() in SSH1.php line 1056
at Net_SSH1->__destruct() in Test.php line 9
at SSHServer->__construct() in Test.php line 9
at Test->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Test), 'index'), array()) in compiled.php line 8287
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in compiled.php line 8354
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(Test), object(Route), 'index') in compiled.php line 8333
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8952
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8935
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8334
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(Test), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in compiled.php line 8320
```

I have been trying to get this working for over a day now and it has finally annoyed me too much....

Comment: Have you considered using other SSH libraries, including those made specifically for Laravel? Or is there anything preventing you from using such libraries? https://github.com/phanan/remote/blob/master/README.md is an example.

Comment: Thats what I did. And that seems to work. My other issue though is that laravel breaks the page with Woops there was an error. Im trying to disable that because I would like to have my own exception screens